# Replacing values of a column which is of type list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df_result` that looks like this-
The `Similar Products` column have lists of IDs which are similar to the corresponding `Product Name`

```
Product Name       Similar Products
Apple              [5,6,99,7]
Mango              [8,6]
Litchi             []
```

I want to replace these IDs with their name. I have  dictionary `product_id_name` that has the mapping of ID with name like this-

```
{ 
5: 'Green Apple'
6:'Fruit'
8:'Pineapple'
....
}
```

I have done the following -

```
df_result = df_result[df_result['Similar Products'].map(lambda x :[product_id_name[element] for element in x])]
```

but it throws an error `unhashable type: 'list'`
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Should be `[product_id_name[element] for element in x]` no?

Comment: I am sorry I did that only. Let me edit.Same error.

Comment: Right because you're filtering the dataframe with a series of lists. That should be `df_result['Similar Products'] = df_result['Similar Products'].map(lambda x: [product_id_name[element] for element in x])`

Comment: Omg such a dumb mistake from my end. Thanks a lot @Henry

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Henry,

```
df_result['Similar Products'] = df_result['Similar Products'].map(lambda x: [product_id_name[element] for element in x])
```